# Django - Gunicorn/Nginx - 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: python, django, unix, nginx, gunicorn

Need Help on 502 Bad Gateway ngnix/1.10.3

I have configured my Django application using Nginx/Gunicorn. It was running fine until I made some changes to the code and reloaded the server.

FYI: My settings.py has ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

[image]

Error Logs :

```
2018/06/27 08:36:38 [crit] 7444#7444: *35 connect() to unix://home/ubuntu/www/MySite/MySite.sock failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: 106.51.16.0, server: 18.191.255.247, request: "GET /report/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix://home/ubuntu/www/MySite/MySite.sock:/report/", host: "18.191.255.247"
2018/06/27 08:36:40 [crit] 7444#7444: *35 connect() to unix://home/ubuntu/www/MySite/MySite.sock failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: 106.51.16.0, server: 18.191.255.247, request: "GET /report/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix://home/ubuntu/www/MySite/MySite.sock:/report/", host: "18.191.255.247"
2018/06/27 08:36:41 [crit] 7444#7444: *35 connect() to unix://home/ubuntu/www/MySite/MySite.sock failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: 106.51.16.0, server: 18.191.255.247, request: "GET /report/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix://home/ubuntu/www/MySite/MySite.sock:/report/", host: "18.191.255.247"
2018/06/27 08:39:06 [crit] 7444#7444: *41 connect() to unix://home/ubuntu/www/MySite/MySite.sock failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: 106.51.16.0, server: 18.191.255.247, request: "GET /report/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix://home/ubuntu/www/MySite/MySite.sock:/report/", host: "18.191.255.247"
```

Update 1 :

This is my nginx config. Is there any issue with this?

/etc/nginx/sites-available/MySite

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 18.191.255.247;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/ubuntu/www/MySite;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix://home/ubuntu/www/MySite/MySite.sock;
    }
}
```

How do i verify nginx daemon permission to the project folder (//unix://home/ubuntu/www/MySite)

Comment: It seems to me that either your nginx configuration is faulty or the nginx daemon does not have the rights to interact with gunicorn/project folder.

Comment: @SimasJoneliunas What info you might need to help me clarify this.  FYI please check the updated question.

Comment: I don't see any link with your comment.

Comment: Sorry, failed to post the link properly.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51054061/django-gunicorn-nginx-502-bad-gateway?noredirect=1#comment89099991_51054061

Answer (score 1):

Try manually setting the proxy pass URL to the port gunicorn is running the project on the server like:

```
location / {
                proxy_pass         http://localhost:8000;
                proxy_redirect     off;
                proxy_set_header   Host              $http_host;
                proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_connect_timeout 500;
                proxy_read_timeout 600;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a config issue

```
location / {
     include proxy_params;
     proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/www/MySite/MySite.sock;
}

/etc/init.d/nginx restart
```

use below command to check on the permission of socket file

```
ls -l /home/ubuntu/www/MySite/MySite.sock
```